# What does "Tartuffism" mean?

Tags: meaning, philosophy

In the book of Nietzsche called "On the Genealogy of Morals" there is this sentence:

> Let us speak out this new demand: we need a critique of moral values, the value of these values is for the first time to be called into question—and for this purpose a knowledge is necessary of the conditions and circumstances out of which these values grew, and under which they experienced their evolution and their distortion (morality as a result, as a symptom, as a mask, as Tartuffism, as disease, as a misunderstanding; but also morality as a cause, as a remedy, as a stimulant, as a fetter, as a drug), especially as such a knowledge has neither existed up to the present time nor is even now generally desired.

So, does anyone know what "Tartuffism" mean? Search over the internet didn't give anything satisfactory. I didn't find corresponding noun or verb. I would be eager to find out what does it mean.

Comment: Did you look up [Tartuffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartuffe)?

Comment: One would assume that it is a reference to the play Tartuffe by Molière.

Comment: @Hot Licks: in fact, I assume it is a reference to the character Tartuffe in that play.

Comment: https://librivox.org/tartuffe-by-moliere/

Comment: And [the suffix "-ism"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ism) can be applied to just about any word (with varying degrees of meaning or nonsense).

Answer (score 3):

[*Tartuffe*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Tartuffe) was a religious hypocrite and the principal character in Moliere's *Tartuffe [1664]*.

> **Tartuffe** 
>   *noun* 
>   *literary or humorous* 
>   A religious hypocrite, or a hypocritical pretender to excellence of any kind

I would take Tartuffism therefore to mean hypocrisy.

Comment: Hm... Particularly hear, as the issue is about morality, "Tartuffism" will mean behavioural, mental hypocrisy?!

Comment: Yes, I agree--it would mean hypocrisy. I'll edit my answer slightly.